# Adding Stuff into a Gridview with a For-Loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, datagridview

I'm trying to get some Data into my Datagridview with a For-Loop

But the thing is, my Loop jumps out if my counter is at 2 for no reason and I dont know why

This is my Code:

```
var row = new DataGridViewRow();
//image directory
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Daniel\Pictures");

//getting all files from the Directory
foreach(FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
{

    try
    {
         this.img16x16.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(file.FullName));

    }catch
    {
         Console.WriteLine("This is not an image file");
    }
}
for (int j = 0; j <= this.img16x16.Images.Count; j++)
{

    dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value = img16x16.Images[j].ToString();
    img16x16.ImageSize = new Size(16, 16);
    dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value = img16x16.Images[j];
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
```

Thanks for your help

edit: I found the solution, i just had to put these 2:

```
var row = new DataGridViewRow();
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
```

in front of my code inside the for-loop

Comment: For one thing, your loop will get an exception at the end. <= count should be < count

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you I didn't noticed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've mixed up your row variable and the datagrid's rows.

```
for(int j = 0;  j < this.img16x16.Images.Count; j++)
{
    row = new DataGridViewRow();
    //Add first cell and its data to the variable "row"
    //Size changes
    //Add second cell and its data to the variable "row"

    //Add "row" to the grid:
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

In your version you were writing straight to the grid without any reference to its size, and I'm guessing it was one or two rows large by some other settings you have, and you tried to write outside its bounds.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i found the solution and edited it into my Thread :)